# Java несколько окон JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте. Я новичок в программировании и есть у меня "ламерский" вопрос. 
Есть 2 формы JFrame(назовем их form1 и form2). Как сделать, чтобы по нажатию кнопки в одной форме, данная форма закрылась и открылась другая? 
Правильно ли будет сделать так -  при нажатии на кнопку, visible form1 установить как false и след. строчка кода form2 = new JFrame();
Хочется делать все правильно)

Answer (score 4):

Давайте начнем разбираться :)

где-то в коде должно появиться примерно следущие:

```
JFrame form1 = new JFrame("form1");
JButton button = new JButton("visible");
form1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
form1.setSize(350,150);
form1.add(button);
form1.setVisible(true);

//а теперь главное - обработчик событий кнопки
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              //а вот тут как раз код чего делать при нажатии на кнопку
              //в самом простом виде следующие:
              JFrame form2 = new JFrame("form2");
              form2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              form2.setSize(350,150);
              //не видим первую форму
              form1.setVisible(false);
              //открываем вторую
              form2.setVisible(true);
         }
    });
```

тут другой вопрос интереснее - чего с потоками, как и где создаются фреймы(в каком месте и можно ли их так просто закрыть) и т.д.. От этого напрямую зависит как вызывать обработку нажатия на кнопку и где.

Comment: Спасибо, я так все и представлял

Comment: Вообще-то это отвратительно. Почитайте оба про MVC и про MVP. Хватит уже Delphi лепить везде где ни попадя.

Comment: Бинго! Но если человек спрашивает про то, как оно должно работать, то ни о каких мвс или мвп речи идти не может

Comment: Ну вот пусть и читает про них, там всё будет рассказано ;)

Answer (score 3):

Все рисование библиотеки Swing происходит в отдельном потоке. Поэтому будет лучше и свое рисование переносить в этот поток. Это достигается при помощи создания анонимного класса и передачи его как параметра в метод invokeLater библиотеки Swing.

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
{
   run() {

     form1.setVisible(false);
     form2.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: Зачем это делать, если вызываться это будет из обработчика нажатия на кнопку?

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Действительно, обработчик нажатия как раз происходит в потоке рисования swing и для этого случая invokeLater не имеет смысла. Рисование же из других потоков рекомендуется делать вышеуказанным способом.

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже новичок, но думаю, что нужно сделать так:

```
SwingUtilites.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   run() {
     form1.setVisible(false);
   }
});
form2.setVisible(true);
```